# How to print odd or even numbers?

Tags: javascript

How can I print the next few even or odd numbers following a number given by the user? The Looping Part Of the code is not executed as expected

Here's my attempt:

```js
       var x;
    var   y=10;
    x=prompt("Enter a number : ")
    var  total=x+y;
    
   
    
    if(x%2==0&&x>0)
    {
        for(;x<=total;x+=2)
       {
            document.write("<h2> Next few even No. after Your No. are : "+x+"<br></h2>");
       }
    }
    if(x%2!==0&&x>0)
    {
        for(;x<=total;x+=2)
        {
        document.write("<h2> Next few odd No. after your No. are :" +x+"<br></h2>");
        }
    }
```

Comment: *"consider the following code and Tell What is Wrong"* - Start with why you **think** something is wrong.  Does the code fail in some way?  Does it produce an error?  An unexpected result?  When you debug the code, is there a specific operation which produces an unexpected result?  Be specific.

Answer (score 1):

My best tip for you is to step through the code and try to think like the JavaScript interpreter, statement by statement, expression by expression. It helps to keep notes on the state of your variables for each step. Thankfully we don't have to go far to find the problem in this case.

```
var x;
```

This declares a variable `x`, which is not initialized to a value, which is to say its value is `undefined`.

```
var   y=10;
```

This is declaring a variable `y` initialized to the `Number` 10.

```
var  total=x+y;
```

This declares a variable `total` and it initializes it to the value of the expression `x+y`. Since `x` is `undefined` and `y` is `10`, that means it's equivalent to:

```
var total = undefined + 10
```

What do you expect the result of adding a number and undefined to be? Probably not a number. JavaScript "cleverly" evaluates it to the special value `NaN` which stands for exactly that, "not a number."

Now as you reference `total` further down in the code, you might expect that it's not going to behave as you planned. Now ask yourself, what *do* you want `total` to be set to, and how should you change your code to get there?

It's tedious stepping through each statement like this, but that's really the best way to debug problems. You can even use a step debugger by setting a breakpoint on the line of code and interactively see the code execute. You'll eventually get to the point where you can mentally evaluate the code like the machine does almost reflexively.